# log-logistic distribution probability density integration

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

So I have a probability density that I want to integrate:

$$\int^y_0\frac{e^\theta\lambda u^{\lambda-1}}{(1+e^\theta u^\lambda)^2}du$$

Apparently this is equal to:

$$\frac{e^\theta y^\lambda}{1+e^\theta y^\lambda}$$

But I cannot see how? Partial fractions doesn't work, neither does integrating by parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x=1+e^\theta u^\lambda \Rightarrow dx=e^\theta\lambda u^{\lambda-1}du$

$dx=e^\theta\lambda u^{\lambda-1}du \Rightarrow \int\frac{e^\theta\lambda u^{\lambda-1}}{(1+e^\theta u^\lambda)^2}du=\int\frac1{x^2}dx=-\frac1x$

$\int\frac{e^\theta\lambda u^{\lambda-1}}{(1+e^\theta u^\lambda)^2}du=-\frac1{1+e^\theta u^\lambda} \Rightarrow \int^y_0\frac{e^\theta\lambda u^{\lambda-1}}{(1+e^\theta u^\lambda)^2}du=F(y)-F(0)=1-\frac{1}{1+e^{\theta}y^{\lambda}}=\frac{e^\theta y^\lambda}{1+e^\theta y^\lambda}
$

Comment: I forgot substitution, thank you

Comment: I do not understand the last line, how does the LHS imply the RHS?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\text{Hint: } \int^y_0\frac{e^\theta\lambda u^{\lambda-1}}{(1+e^\theta u^\lambda)^2} \, du = \int^y_0\frac 1 {(1+e^\theta u^\lambda)^2} \Big( e^\theta\lambda u^{\lambda-1} \, du\Big)
$$